# Embed an External Page Without an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, iframe, embed

Is there any way to embed an external web page without using an iframe? I have access to both sites, I just want the page that the content is embedded on to resize based on the content that is embedded (it will change over time, and be on multiple sites).

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't think any kind of AJAX would work because it's cross-site, and JavaScript doesn't let you load off-site content (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could load the external page with jquery:

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
//would this help
```

Comment: +1 - I think you will still need to allow a cross domain ajax call from www.orginaldomain.com to www.somesite.com.

Comment: I don't think you can use javascript includes because it's limited for security reasons. DefyGravity, how would I go about that?

Comment: This code depends on external page enable "allow-control-allow-origin: *", which you cannot guarantee.

Comment: this is not work in SharePoint like web parts. Did SharePoint not permit to me to load other files by js? @FlavioEscobar

Answer (score 37):

Or you could use the object tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/7MaXx/

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="http://www.google.be">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.flickr.com" style="width:100%; height:100%">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Object tag has problem with height. even if give height:100%; still does not work. work only with fixed height value. Else need to get the external web page 's height and width. that something I could't find yet. If you could please help

Comment: you can set the height to something like 2500px or something... I have the same issue.

Comment: For my case I had to display a dynamically created HTML content inside Object. I was replacing the data attribute of the object tag runtime using jQuery as follows.

element.attr('data',"data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+escape(HTMLContent))

and it worked like charm .

Comment: WOAW !! Just perfect where all solutions have failed for me ! Big thx !

Comment: Very interesting. Will the html from the data= tag be able to interact with the parent page? For instance, if the page at data= has javascripts and css, can that javascript and css also effect the parent and its elements? Ty

Comment: setting the height to using a viewport height unit - height: 99vh, fixes the height issue

Answer (score 2):

Question is good, but the answer is : it depends on that.

If the other webpage doesn't contain any form or text, for example you can use the CURL method  to pickup  the exact content and after then showing on your page. YOu can do it without using an iframe.

But, if the page what you want to embed contains for example a form it will not work correctly , because the form handling is on that site.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use PHP!  It's all server side:

```
<?php print file_get_contents("http://foo.com")?>
```

If you own both sites, you may need to ok this transaction with full declaration of headers at the server end.  Works beautifully.

Comment: Php will do the jpb fine,  producing extra load to your server.  Client side solutions (js) will keep your server nice and fresh

Answer (score 1):

HTML Imports, part of the Web Components cast, is also a way to include HTML documents in other HTML documents. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/