# Trying to open other website content in My website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm trying to open the other website content in my website

```
<iframe src="http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/default.aspx">
```

I've tried using the Iframe . it works well but it doesn't open all the url.

What's the workaround for this?
Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: what URL are you trying to open?

Comment: @Melissa Hie
<iframe src="http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/default.aspx">

Comment: Why did you write your entire question in bold? Formatting should be used to only highlight certain words of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by “it works well but it doesn't open all the url”? If you mean “it works well for some URLs but not all”, then the answer is simply that some servers disallow it, on purpose. Any workaround that works would probably be regarded as illegal (copyright infringement).

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery to do it:

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.example.com");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

and you can read more on :
[Embed an External Page Without an Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433319/embed-an-external-page-without-an-iframe)

Comment: You should mention that loading cross domain content will fail in most cases. As is needs to be allowed by the foreign server.

Comment: Whenever you just do a copy&past of an already existing answer which out adding any additional relevant information, then you either don't answer the question, or the question is a duplicate of the one where you copied your answer from.

Comment: @t.niese You're right, this is just because it was my first experience in stackoverflow.