# Issues with how to "Embed an External Page Without an Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I have been trying to follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433319/embed-an-external-page-without-an-iframe) question, but have been having an issue. Namely: it doesn't work. I have been trying to do the method described in the second answer (the one that uses the object tag). This is the code that I am putting in my body tag:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="http://www.google.be">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.flickr.com" style="width:100%; height:100%">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```

*This* above code does not work. Flickr is not loaded and nothing appears on the page other than a poll by some other site that is totally unaffiliated with me. I don't know why that is loaded. It is definitely from this code and it happens whether or not that first section is there. I think that it may be because of "< p >backup content< /p >" (the spaces are so that it is not reformatted as HTML).

I have also tried giving the object a set height (2500px) but that does nothing.

Does anybody know why this is not working?

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<object>` for loading HTML documents is essentially an `<iframe>` with some features missing and with worse documentation. Use an iframe.

Comment: @Quentin - will an iframe load flickr.com (for example) in effect scaled to the iframe's proportions? Will it be interactive (I can click buttons in the iframe etc.)

Comment: It won't scale the content of it, the content will be interactive, just like an `<object>` if you got that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my JavaScript console when I try to run that code in Firefox:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.flickr.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.

Flickr doesn't allow you to put its homepage in a frame (and a frame created by an object element is still a frame).

Comment: Would jQuery get around this?

Comment: No. You can't override security settings from third party sites with client side code.

Comment: ok. good to know. Is there a way to check if a website does not allow itself to be put in an iframe?

Comment: Look at the HTTP headers it sends in its responses or look for that error message in your console when you try.