# Browse Another Website Inside MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, cross-domain

I have an existing web application which I want to display inside my new application, so as to the complete application works inside the new application.

In the image i've attached google.com so on search of something is should show the result or even open the website.

I'm not sure how to achieve that.

One way I found is IFrame, so would I to know any other possibilities are their as I do want to use IFrame

Attaching an Image for an example[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like fancybox tools. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples
But usually these tools are also using iframes. Maybe you can find another way for fancybox.

edit:[Embed an External Page Without an Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433319/embed-an-external-page-without-an-iframe)

edit 2: did you try this?
http://www.felgall.com/noiframe.htm

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Ilker Test
    <br />
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <object classid="CLSID:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13"
        data="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp" style="height:800px; width:1200px; overflow:hidden;">
        </object>
        <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!-->
    <object type="text/html" data="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp"
            style="height:800px; width:1200px;">
        <p>Alternate text.</p>
    </object>
    <!--><![endif]-->
    </object>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried the link as well, but then some java script conflicts are coming

Comment: You can try download html codes from target website and show it with html.raw

Comment: what i want is that the complete website should be working inside my application not just want to display 1 page